# Clear up memory in python loop after creating a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, memory, gpflow

I am running a for loop in python where each loop is required to create a model on different data (an extract is shown below). The model created each time is not erased from memory resulting in slowing down each loop.

```
import gc
for s in range(0, 5):
  X, Y = get_data()
  m = make_dgp_model(X, Y, Z_100, L)
  del m
  gc.collect()
  print('memory: {}'.format(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000000))
```

Giving output:

```
memory: 460.025856
memory: 470.310912
memory: 486.764544
memory: 493.457408
memory: 499.523584
```

I understand that python uses pointer reference for its memory and it does not rewrite something in memory when the variable, is reused. For that reason I tried del m and then using a garbage collector. Which doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? And is there a way I can completely delete what is stored in `m` once the loop is done?

Comment: Why are you trying to handle memory usage in Python? That is not a thing you should worry about.

Comment: Each loop gets slowed down significantly due to the increase in memory.

Comment: Why should it? Perhaps you should show some of the code, and explain what X, Y, Z_100 and L are.

Comment: I have encountered similar memory and slowdown problems using `tensorflow` and `keras` models in python. Are you using any of this in `make_dgp_model`?

Comment: @KrisR89 My model is a deep gaussian process using tensorflow according to this implementation. https://github.com/ICL-SML/Doubly-Stochastic-DGP/blob/master/doubly_stochastic_dgp/dgp.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was my initial thought as to why the slowdown occurs, I might be wrong though. X and Y are both lists of floats and make_dgp_model returns a deep gaussian process model based in tensorflow.

Comment: Thats the problem than, `del m` does not clear the tensorflow parameter in the tensorflow session. I think restarting the session at each loop can work, but it takes a while each time you restart!
what is the reason for the re-create of the model? You can often get around this by editing the existing model instead of re-create.

Comment: I am working with time series data (where I am using a rolling window over it) and I am fitting a regression model to each rolling window hence, I am fitting a different model in each loop.

Comment: I guess you possible could reinitialize the weights at each loop instead of creating a new model? That should give the same result without the memory leak

Comment: If you are not using eager mode, you are probably adding new versions of the model to the graph. Even if you `del m`, the graph and its operations will still exist. If you have not created a graph yourself, the graph would be given be `tf.get_default_graph()`, and you can clear it (replace it with a new, empty graph) with `tf.reset_default_graph()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPflow's readme page has a link to the nice **tips and tricks** notebook. There you can find an answer on your question in the item number one :)

https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/tips_and_tricks.ipynb

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this issue was to add the following in order to reset the graph at each loop.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
gpflow.reset_default_session(graph=graph)
```

As shown in [this](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/719) github issue (see last comment).

Comment: There is a built-in utility function for this: `gpflow.reset_default_graph_and_session()`

Comment: @STJ. Do you know if there is a similar function in pytorch as I am having the same trouble with in pytorch however.